# converting include file in C to python

Tags: python, regex, text-processing

I am a python newbie. My objective is to convert a include file in C to python. For example.

input file (stdincl.c)

```
#define STDIN_BASEADDRESS 0x40600000
#define STDOUT_BASEADDRESS 0x40600000

/******************************************************************/

/* Definitions for driver UARTLITE */
#define XPAR_XUARTLITE_NUM_INSTANCES 1
```

expected output file (reg.py)

```
def STDIN_BASEADDRESS ():
    return 0x40600000
def STDOUT_BASEADDRESS ():
    return 0x40600000
# Definitions for driver UARTLITE 
def XPAR_XUARTLITE_NUM_INSTANCES ():
    return 1
```

I have tried to write codes using dictionary to hold a set of patterns to be replaced but it didnot really work. Any ideas is appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#define` lines create constants. Just create variables in python for those:

```
STDIN_BASEADDRESS = 0x40600000
STDOUT_BASEADDRESS = 0x40600000

# ******************************************************************

# Definitions for driver UARTLITE
XPAR_XUARTLITE_NUM_INSTANCES = 1
```

So all you need to do is remove the `#define` part, and insert a `=` equals sign. A set of regular expressions would do the job:

```
import re
from functools import partial

replacements = (
    partial(re.compile(r'\s*#define ([A-Z_]+) (.*)').sub, r'\1 = \2'),
    partial(re.compile(r'\s*/\*\s*(.*?)\s*\*/').sub, r'# \1'),
)   

for line in inputsequence:
    for transform in replacements:
        line = transform(line)
    print line
```

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> from functools import partial
>>> replacements = (
...     partial(re.compile(r'\s*#define ([A-Z_]+) (.*)').sub, r'\1 = \2'),
...     partial(re.compile(r'\s*/\*\s*(.*?)\s*\*/').sub, r'# \1'),
... )   
>>> for line in inputsequence:
...     for transform in replacements:
...         line = transform(line)
...     print line
... 
STDIN_BASEADDRESS = 0x40600000
STDOUT_BASEADDRESS = 0x40600000

# ****************************************************************

# Definitions for driver UARTLITE
XPAR_XUARTLITE_NUM_INSTANCES = 1
```

If you still want to transform the defines to functions, just adjust the replacement pattern:

```
partial(re.compile(r'\s*#define ([A-Z_]+) (.*)').sub, r'def \1():\n    return \2'),
```

which results in:

```
def STDIN_BASEADDRESS():
    return 0x40600000
def STDOUT_BASEADDRESS():
    return 0x40600000

# ****************************************************************

# Definitions for driver UARTLITE
def XPAR_XUARTLITE_NUM_INSTANCES():
    return 1
```

Comment: Thanks Martijn, I tried to run the code. I get an error.                                                              line = tranform(line) 
NameError: name 'tranform' is not defined

Answer (score 1):

You can use on linux and probably Mac OS X some other text processing tools

> `cat "<PATH TO YOUR FILE>" | awk '/^#define/ {printf("%s = %s",$2,$3)}' > "<PATH TO *.PY>"`